# Clicking and moving values from value selector to value selected in spans

Tags: java, selenium

I have a popup that has two spans in it. (kindly see the attached image also). I have to click any one country's name and then click the arrow in the center to move that country's name to the span in the right side.

I my CSS is as below:

```
<tr>
<td/>
<td width="252" class="headerRow">
Text -  Available Spoken Languages 
<font id="lblCount"/>
<td/>
<td/>
<td/>
<td class="headerRow">
Text -  Selected Spoken Languages         Preferred   <td/>
<tr height="2">
<td/>
<td/>
<td/>
<tr>
<td/>
<td height="227" rowSpan="3">
<span id="SelectBorder" style="width: 252px; height: 227px;">
<select name="lstLanguages" tabIndex="7" id="lstLanguages" style="width: 257px; color: black; text-decoration: none;" ondblclick="InsertLanguage()" size="15">
<option value="44">
Text - Abkhazian
<option value="134">
Text - Afar!
```

The Arrow's CSS is:

```
<img width="16" height="15" tabIndex="8" title="Add Language" style="top: 25px; position: relative; cursor: hand;" onclick="InsertLanguage()" src="../Images/V10Icons/Right.gif"/>
```

---

I am using Java, Selenium, Win 8, IE 10.
kindly help me as I am trying to click value from the left span and then click the right arrow in the center to move it to the right span. I am not even able to find any label etc to click the very 1st value. please help

Comment: Which element in your HTML is the arrow?

Comment: <img width="16" height="15" tabIndex="8" title="Add Language" style="top: 25px; position: relative; cursor: hand;" onclick="InsertLanguage()" src="../Images/V10Icons/Right.gif"/>    .... this is the arrow CSS

Comment: It is not added to question description. You should add things like this there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is not very clear, but this may work:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//option[@value='44']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@title='Add Language']")).click();
```

Comment: I have added the Arrows CSS as well. Does the above code need some ammendment? or is it good to go ?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't provide it.